# How to understand a example about Array.prototype.copyWithin()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin?v=example) This is original link.

I am learning Array.prototype from MDN. Now, I was troubled by a example about Array.prototype.copyWithin(). Please help me, thanks for your helping.

For example, the following code could be understanded by me, and the running answer is equal to my answer. I think the first code is understanded like the second code. So, I know the answer.

```
console.log( [].copyWithin.call(new Int32Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 0, 3, 4) ); // TypedArray => [4, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log( new Int32Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).copyWithin(0,3,4) ); // TypedArray => [4, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But, the next code, I cannot understand.

`console.log( [].copyWithin.call({length: 5, 3: 1}, 0, 3) ); // How to execute?`

These examples are from Mozilla Developer Network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Array#copyWithin` method can be called with any object with `Function#call`, as long as it has a `length` property and numeric keys. The code on MDN calls the `Array#copyWithin` as the object `{ length: 5, 3: 1 }` as it's `this` or instance value. It is "the array" the method is operating on.

An *array* is just an object, a special one with `length` and numeric, ordered properties. The same thing is happening here. Instead of an array, they're "mocking" an array by passing an object with `length` and numeric keys.

The same operation happens because both an array and `{ length: 5, 3: 1 }`:

- Have the `length` property
- Have numeric keys

Comment: I see. When codes like ' [].copyWithin.call(Object, arguments) ', the arguments of copyWithin() are key of the Object. Instead of an Array, the arguments are index of an Array.  I had a narrow understanding about Array ago.Thank a lot.